# Runtime error when computing difference of two SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL, I have a table called `Student` which has a field called `Score`. I would like to get the value of the 5th `Score`.

So far, I have tried getting the first 5 scores and subtracting the first 4:

```
SELECT TOP 5 Score
FROM Student
ORDER BY Score
WHERE Score NOT IN ( SELECT TOP 4 Score
                      FROM Student
                      ORDER BY Score )
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
Runtime Error Message:
Line 2: SyntaxError: near '5 Score
FROM Student
ORDER BY Score
WHERE Score NOT IN ( SELECT TOP 4 Score
```

I can't figure out what's the cause of this.

Comment: MySQL doesn't have a `TOP` (you're perhaps reading SQL Server documentation by accident?) The MySQL equivalent would be [`LIMIT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `LIMIT` with an offset:

```
SELECT Score
FROM Student
ORDER BY Score DESC
LIMIT 4,1;  -- Retrieve row 5
```

This will select the row with the 5th *highest* score. Omit `DESC` if you want the row having the 5th *lowest* score.

**Note:** `TOP` is not available in MySQL RDBMS.